# Can Spotfire change data table source directory based on username?

Tags: sharepoint, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

We'd like to distribute a Spotfire dashboard to different users, however the location of the data source file is on Sharepoint and for every user it's mapped to:

C:\Users\myusername\Sharepoint\spotfiretable.csv

Where myusername is the windows login account username and if I gave someone this Spotfire file they'd have to get prompted to re-direct Spotfire to the same folder mapped under their user name. Is there any way to avoid this and have Spotfire recognize the location of the data source automatically by getting the username information from system environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

I would try embedding the data source in the dxp/ analysis with no data just the column names. This way visual ect don't have to be recreated.

Set up a python script to update the data source to the user name path and refresh the table. You can even trigger this event on load so it would be seemless for end user.

Here is a link showing python script to updated data source. 
https://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/05/replace-data-tables-from-file.html?m=1

If you require assistance with the python script post a new question with what code you've tried to implement.